# mode_rewrite match one slash only

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have been wrecking my brain.

I need to match

```
dictionary/word
```

and redirect to

```
dictionary/en/word
```

my regex is as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(dictionary/(\w+))$ dictionary/en/$2 [R=301,L]
```

However I am getting a redirect loop. Does anyone have a solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/(\w+)$ dictionary/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the request is `directory/word` then `(\w+)` should match `word`, and it should be available in `$1`.

BTW, you don't need to scape fordward slashes here, so `\/` is the same as `/`.

Comment: thank you. I had tried that before. I had to change where I was placing my condition. I placed it before    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Answer (score 1):

try escaping `/`

```
RewriteRule ^(dictionary\/(\w+))$ dictionary/en/$2 [R=301,L]
```